# problem when binding mysql tinyint with subsonic 3 and datagridview

Tags: mysql, subsonic, subsonic3

i created a datalayer using subsonic. however when i am selecting my data, i get the following exception.

```
    System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message="Object of type 'System.Boolean' cannot be converted to type 'System.SByte'."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
       at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
       at SubSonic.Extensions.Database.Load[T](IDataReader rdr, T item, List`1 ColumnNames)
       at SubSonic.Extensions.Database.ToEnumerable[T](IDataReader rdr, List`1 ColumnNames)
       at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Execute[T](QueryCommand`1 query, Object[] paramValues)
       at lambda_method(ExecutionScope )
       at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
       at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.QueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
       at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at TorontoTrader.Data.Ver2.ninjascan.Find(Expression`1 expression) in E:\TradingTools\CODE\TorontoTraderDataVer2\TorontoTraderDataVer2\ActiveRecord.cs:line 4148
       at TorontoTraderAlerts.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\TradingTools\CODE\TorontoTraderDataVer2\TorontoTraderAlerts\Form1.cs:line 24
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at TorontoTraderAlerts.Program.Main() in E:\TradingTools\CODE\TorontoTraderDataVer2\TorontoTraderAlerts\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 

the code segment wher its throwing it is 

public static IList<ninjascan> Find(Expression<Func<ninjascan, bool>> expression) {

            var repo = GetRepo();
            return repo.Find(expression).ToList();
        }

the column in Mysql is TinyInt (Length=1)

dunno how to fix it.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your mysql connection string add a "Treat Tiny As Boolean" parameter, e.g.:

```
Server=srv;Database=db;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;Treat Tiny As Boolean=true;
```

this should force the MySQL.Data connector to return true or false for TINYINT(1) instead.

The mysql docs claim that this seems to be the default behavior

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

but I am pretty sure that false was the default in earlier versions.